# How to make the lowercase font in Math Sans font in pdfTeX, LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, sans-serif, sansmathfonts

I want to make this font with `LaTeX`:

For example, to show you: that is ,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages offering sans serif math fonts including `sansmathfonts`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts}

\begin{document}

$\alpha \beta \gamma + abc$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried this before!

Comment: @gopoke so why ask question?